# What would I expect to read from a disconnected SPI port?

Tags: spi, linux, floating

I'm writing a program that reads from a SPI port.  However, there's some complicated logic that controls whether the slave is physically connected to the port (if not, the lines are left floating).

Currently, I'm receiving consistent garbage data (consistently the same wrong byte, 0x05).  Is this a plausible outcome if the other device is not connected and the SPI lines are left floating?

Comment: It really depends on the MCU you are using. Most of the chips that I use have built-in pull-ups (though they are not always enabled by default). 0x05 doesn't seem likely to me, unless there is some coupling to your MOSI output and you are transmitting something similar.

Comment: The pins are configurable to pull up, down, or neither.  Currently, they are configured to float.

Comment: @Mark w.r.t 0x05 not seeming likely: This reading is taken immediately after sending out 0x7f to request that a specific register be read.  At 10 MHz, I consistently get 0x05, but at other data rates I sometimes get different bytes (and sometimes it's not consistent).  I would expect to get 0x0b.

Comment: As @Turbo J said, the trace is probably acting as an antenna and picking-up something that is running synchronous with your SPI access. Doesn't your MCU have internal pull-ups?

Comment: Suggest you try changing the MISO pin to pull-up or pull-down. Without a slave connected, you should see 0xff or 0x00 respectively. I agree that a consistent 0x05 seems unlikely.

Comment: @g.rocket - If I had your hardware, I would use an oscilloscope to view the SPI master input signal (e.g. MISO or whatever it is called on your SPI master). Testing would include checking for evidence of crosstalk onto this (undriven?) signal and its voltage level, and checking whether attaching the 'scope changed the received data byte from 0x05 to something else. Attaching a 'scope will affect the electrical characteristics of the signal (an unfortunate reality of testing) but to minimise that effect, use an active probe, or at least a x10 probe. If you do this, please supply 'scope capture.

Comment: Using a weak, internal pull up/down of the MCU on the input or choosing another device on the bus that uses a bus-keeper MISO port would be a good general decision.

Answer (score 3):

> if not, the lines are left floating

Floating CMOS inputs are **bad**. They will work as antennas and you will read garbage - and consume additional current when there is enough HF noise to triger *fast* switching beween high and low.

I recommand using a pullup or pulldown resistor, 10 kOhm usually works well.

Comment: This isn't answering my question.  Is what I'm seeing a plausible consequence of reading from floating SPI lines, or is there some other root cause at work here?

Comment: It's plausible, yes, but up-leveling for a second, the presence of floating inputs throws basically everything out the windows because you can't guarantee anything. I understand if you're a SW guy trying to figure out if its a SW vs. HW problem, but the root design issue here IMO is that the design has a SPI link that might be operated when some pins are floating. I just don't think it's worth the time to investigate this further knowing that pins are floating.